# VS reporting stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error

My platform is Windows 7 x64. This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string line;
    int c = 3;

    while(c-- && getline(cin, line))
    {
        stringstream sstr;
        sstr << line;

        uint32_t data;

        int r = sscanf(sstr.str().c_str(), "%d", &data);

        if (r == 1)
        {
            cout << data << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

takes integer numbers as input, prints them and exists fine. If I  change the type of `data` to `uint16_t`, then just before returning from main() function, VS 2010 throws an error:

**Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'data' was corrupted**

I was wondering why VS 2010 is so angry at `uint16_t`? Any explanation?

Comment: Well, what is the size of an `int` on your platform?

Comment: as Oli said, my guess would be the integer size

Comment: it's 4 byte @OliCharlesworth

Comment: @Donotalo: Ok, then does that answer your question?

Comment: I didn't know about `hd`. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `%d` refers to a 32 bit value. Try `%hd` for 16 bit values.